# Mold in toilet's waterline, why?

Tags: plumbing, mold, building, water-tank

Recently I've noticed mold forming in the water line inside the toilet's seat. To be honest I was surprised since never in my life have I seen mold forming up in a toilet's waterline. I make sure to clean it often too.

I live in an apartment building and we have a water tank in the rooftop, which is the custom here.
I'm seriously afraid that the whole water supply might be infested with mold, since that could be so harmful long term, yet could easily passed unnoticed.

Is it possible for mold to survive and infest the whole water supply? Sorry if the question is a bit dumb, but I'm just completely ignorant on this matter and need help.

I'm thinking of contacting a lab and do a proper water analysis, but I just want to know if I should even bother or I'm just being paranoid, and the mold is forming for some other reason?

Comment: If the water tank on the roof also supplies drinking/washing water I would have it tested.  It might just be something with the toilet, but why take chances.  Quite a few news stories about people getting sick from water tanks.

Comment: it could be algae instead of mold, but either way i wouldn't drink it. When I lived in mexico the "hot" water was from a rooftop tank and large flat splotches of dark green something would flake off and come out the faucet semi-regularly to the point I would had to switch showerheads to a hose nozzle that didn't clog.